# Why does the cell my image is in not resize with my image?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make a table with 4 cels and in each cell an image. I'm trying with a test image now but whenever I put the size of the image in % (I want the image to resize with the window) the cel the image is in stays the width of the original  image. So the image resizes, but the cel the image is in does not. Only width though, the height does resize. If I put the image size in px, it does work. But that's not what I want... I tried putting the image in my html code, but I get the same result. So I want the image size to be in % so that when you change the width of the window, the image resizes with it.

**This is my code:**

```css
table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}
td {
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
}
.image1 {
    background: url(../afb/test.png);
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!--pictures-->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="image1"></div></td>
        <td>pic 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pic3</td>
        <td>pic4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<div class="image1"</div>` is invalid HTML markup

Comment: `content: url(../afb/test.png);` on an `IMG` tag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this code will help you to solve this issue. Best regards.

```css
        table{
            position:static;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: auto;
            margin-bottom: 20%;
            width:90%;
            height:90%;
        }
        tr , td{
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border:1px solid black;
            margin-left: 10%;
            margin-bottom: 20%;
        }
        td{
            margin: auto;
            padding: auto;
        }
        div.image1 {
            position:relative;
            content: url(http://pirson.me/stackOverSamples/medias/brume.jpg);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="image1"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                pic 2
            </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                pic 3
            </td>
            <td>
                pic 4
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Is this better @HackerFrosch ???

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I change the size of the image in %, the table cel still stays the original width... The image changes size, the height of the cel changes with the image, but the width of the cell still stays at 100% of the original image size

Comment: I also just found out that if i change the width of the image, it changes. But if I change the height of the image, it doesn't change...

Comment: @beginnercoder Did you try to run the snippet in fullscreen on Firefox?

Comment: I'm trying this on Microsoft Edge, and the code works when the image size is 100%, but the cel stays that size whenever i change the image size in %

Comment: @beginnercoder what size is your image?
Could you put a resource online to try it with this file???
With my pictures everything's seems to be alright.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249244/discussion-between-tatactic-and-beginnercoder).